# How to ask router for bandwidth statistics?

Tags: linux, command-line, router, udp

I once heard that there is a UDP protocol for asking a router how much data has moved through it per  minute, but a simple Google search  did not help me  identify it. What is the protocol called, and what Linux utility will let me query the router?  Ideally I would like to graph the results.

I subsequently heard of a Windows utility that pulls down this data from any common household Wifi router.

Given that Netflow (Cisco's technology) requires configuring a Cisco router, I doubt this is what the Windows utility uses.

Comment: Are you trying this for any router? or your home or office router? I know there are ways of doing this through DDWRT if you have that if its yours personally or business related. If you could be more specific on whether you want to go around doing this to every router you connect to or just a home or office router maybe some better answers could be offered.

Comment: Home router.  I heard there was a Windows utility that lets you get these statistics out of the typical home router.

Answer (score 1):

Having this publicly available is usually considered a security issue and so you're unlikely to be able to get this information from another person's router.

If your own router supports the protocol, [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) may be what you're asking about. Tools such as [`snmpnetstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpnetstat) are able to query stats via SNMP remotely.

Comment: Do you know of any host that this command works on?